# How do I salvage this bread dough?

Tags: baking, bread, dough, chemistry, mistakes

I was planning to make a brioche dough, but somehow managed to measure out and add cornstarch instead of bread flour. I've taken as much of the cornstarch out as I can, but there's about 3/4 cup still in there mixed in with the brioche ingredients.

Is there any way to salvage this? I don't need the final result to be brioche, any edible food is fine as long as I dont waste these ingredients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make some sort of bread by adding plenty of the highest protein wheat flour you have. You'll have to judge the hydration when you knead. I'd aim for proportions like a yeast-risen cornbread (or failing that a basic enriched dough) , and make it into rolls, then eat them warm (or reheated). Rising will also be a matter of guesswork/judgment. I find warm bread to be more forgiving when it comes to doneness - a little doughy matters less than when cold. This is even more true if you serve it with soup/chilli/stew for dipping.

Comment: Making rolls is a good idea. You could bake part of the dough as rolls, and if the results are disappointing, salvage the rest by kneading in further high protein flour and water in the appropriate ratio.